# golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt which error case when generating hash

Tags: go, error-handling, bcrypt

This is the function to generate hashed password using [bcrypt](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt)

`func GenerateFromPassword(password []byte, cost int) ([]byte, error)`

> GenerateFromPassword returns the bcrypt hash of the password at the given cost. If the cost given is less than MinCost, the cost will be set to DefaultCost, instead. Use CompareHashAndPassword, as defined in this package, to compare the returned hashed password with its cleartext version.

In which case this function returns an error other than the cost out of range (4, 31)? and the weird thing is they set cost to default when below minimum cost but return an error when the cost is above maximum cost, any reason behind this?

Comment: They set cost to default when below *minimum* cost (not below default) so they can raise the minimum as computing power increases without breaking anyone's code.

Comment: my bad of course, it's set to default below the minimum cost. my point in the last question is why they set error when above maximum cost? why not just set to default as well just like below minimum cost.

Comment: Because it's always a programmer error to specify a value above the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to returning an error for bad parameters, the function returns an error if it cannot read from the secure random number generator.